# iphone landscape width taking the width of portrait mode

Tags: ios, iphone, landscape

I have a fancybox with slider ,the width of the fancybox is set to the width of the screen width the slider is loading fine in all devices except in iphone landscape view,if i view the fancybox slider in landscape view of iphone it is taking the width of the portrait view

Answer (score 0):

In reality, what you want to do is give your slider a proportional width to its superview that way when the phone is in either landscape or portrait it follows that proportion. Worst case scenario you would have to change your size class and add constraints to your slider in that size class. Although that is just a hack, and I don't suggest doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming you created your view in interface builder and you did not configure it to resize when the device rotates. There are two ways to do this:

Old: Springs and struts

New: Autolayout

I would suggest you use Autolayout. Instead of providing a specific link just google "autolayout tutorial" or "introduction to autolayout" and you can pick the link that works best for you to explain that. There are also some tutorials on YouTube. For a bit more of an advanced but comprehensive tutorial try one of the online Stanford videos:
Stanford University Developing iOS 7 Apps: Lecture 9 - Animation and Autolayout
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1sc7NI6-wo

You just need to watch the part about Autolayout and skip the piece about animation.